# how to forward the particular image clicked value to a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

// My Jsp Code

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to Loader</h1>
<c:forEach var="sampleMap" items="${MAP}">
<center><a href="brand1.jsp">
<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/logo/${sampleMap.value}"></a>
<c:set var="brand" value="${sampleMap.value}" scope="session"/>
</center>
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

Using Servlet I am fetching the image from the database and storing in the map ,Fetching in the jsp using for:each and putting in the a href tag so tat i will we work like an image button ..

But My problem is I want to send the image corresponding value to the Servlet when a particular image get clicked and

```
<c:set var="brand" value="${sampleMap.value}" scope="session"/>
```

This above code is always sending the last fetched value ..

Plzz Help

Comment: Put it in the url of the href.

Comment: please elaborate sir.TY @developerwjk

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by putting the value in the url of the href as a parameter:

```
<a href="brand1.jsp?image=${sampleMap.value}">
```

Then in the servlet:

```
request.getParameter("image");
```

Comment: Done! Thanks for your  precious help and time sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to Loader</h1>
<c:forEach var="sampleMap" items="${MAP}">
<center><a href="brand1.jsp?imagevalue=${sampleMap.value}">
<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/logo/${sampleMap.value}"></a>
</center>
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

and use `request.getParameter("iamgeValue");` in your servlet

Comment: Your syntax is wrong.  Using EL is not like concatenating strings in Java. Not `<a href="brand1.jsp?imagevalue="+${sampleMap.value}>` but `<a href="brand1.jsp?imagevalue=${sampleMap.value}">`.  And you would NOT use `request.getAttribute("iamgeValue")` but `request.getParameter("iamgeValue")`.